# Creating URL Paginator with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following data:

- Col a: Specific URL
- Col b: Number of Pages on that URL

I need to create a list of URL with the appended page value at the end

[image]

The end result with excel VBA macro / python should look like this, with the appended `&page=` value at end.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is this:

```
Sub Paginator()
    Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim curCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iCounter As Integer: iCounter = 0

    LastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For Each curCell In sht.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Cells

        For i = 1 To Val(curCell.Offset(, 1))
            iCounter = iCounter + 1
            Cells(iCounter, 3) = curCell & "&page=" & i
        Next i

    Next    

End Sub
```

Modify `i=2` to ignore page 1 values

[image]